# Filling of varchar/char during FOREACH SELECT (loop)

Tags: foreach, char, informix, varchar

I have a question about my self coded informix function.

Does anyone have any idea why the return value of the function is 'x'?
The SELECT statement of the for each head should be return 19 datasets.
Therefore, I would expect the 'x' is to be cascaded 19 times with itself
so the return value of the function is 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

The function which I wrote is:

```
CREATE function mydb.my_function(spAuftNr INTEGER, spPos INTEGER, spUPos INTEGER, spTeileNr INTEGER) 
                     
  RETURNING VARCHAR;                                                                                        
  DEFINE spWs_kz CHAR(1);
  DEFINE spLfdnr CHAR(2);
  DEFINE spLaenge CHAR(10);                                                                                  
  DEFINE spBreite CHAR(10);
  DEFINE spWegfall CHAR(1);
  DEFINE spDicke CHAR(8);                                                                           
  DEFINE spReturn VARCHAR;    
  DEFINE tempy VARCHAR;
  
  LET spReturn = '';                                                                              
                                                                                                             
  FOREACH SELECT to_char(ws_kz),to_char(lfdnr),to_char(laenge),to_char(breite),to_char(wegfall),to_char(dicke) 
  INTO spWs_kz, spLfdnr, spLaenge, spBreite, spWegfall, spDicke from my_table where auftnr = spAuftNr and pos = spPos and u_pos = spUPos and teile_nr = spTeileNr
   

   LET spReturn = spReturn || 'x';
        
                                                                                                         
  END FOREACH                                                                                               
                                                                                                             
  RETURN (spReturn);                                                                                         
END function;
```

I hope someone can help me.
I think you know what is the next step when i can
realize this.

Best regards
Simon

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test this but I think the issue is when you define spReturn as varchar, it's defaulting to varchar (1).  So I think, if you changed that define to say "define spReturn VARCHAR(20)" you would possibly then see all the 'x' values.  You may also need to change the "returning varchar" portion as well.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Strange, I tried defining "RETURNING VARCHAR (255);" and "DEFINE spReturn VARCHAR (255);". But yesterday with the same result. Today I get my 19x "x" s. I will post the corrected version right away yesterday was a long day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong with me yesterday, jrenaut is right. The code should actually be like this::

```
CREATE function mydb.my_function(spAuftNr INTEGER, spPos INTEGER, spUPos INTEGER, spTeileNr INTEGER) 
                     
  RETURNING VARCHAR(255);                                                                                        
  DEFINE spWs_kz CHAR(1);
  DEFINE spLfdnr CHAR(2);
  DEFINE spLaenge CHAR(10);                                                                                  
  DEFINE spBreite CHAR(10);
  DEFINE spWegfall CHAR(1);
  DEFINE spDicke CHAR(8);                                                                           
  DEFINE spReturn VARCHAR(255);    
  DEFINE tempy VARCHAR;
  
  LET spReturn = '';                                                                              
                                                                                                             
  FOREACH SELECT to_char(ws_kz),to_char(lfdnr),to_char(laenge),to_char(breite),to_char(wegfall),to_char(dicke) 
  INTO spWs_kz, spLfdnr, spLaenge, spBreite, spWegfall, spDicke from my_table where auftnr = spAuftNr and pos = spPos and u_pos = spUPos and teile_nr = spTeileNr
   

   LET spReturn = spReturn || 'x';
        
                                                                                                         
  END FOREACH                                                                                               
                                                                                                             
  RETURN (spReturn);                                                                                         
END function;
```

Thanks again for the effort.